# Bad request with Cloudant, PHP and range query

Tags: php, curl, couchdb, cloudant

I'm trying to get a range query to work with PHP cURL and Cloudant.

I've setup the following search index in my Cloudant:

```
{
  "_id": "_design/date",
  "_rev": "20-822ebda694f4fb57dc0a48bf60f6570f",
  "views": {},
  "language": "javascript",
  "indexes": {
    "by_date": {
      "analyzer": "classic",
      "index": "function (doc) {\n  index(\"default\", doc.datequery);\n}"
    }
  }
}
```

And then in my PHP document I do the following:

```
$urlstuff = "[20180110 TO 20180119]";

$url = "https://user:pass.@user.cloudant.com/db/_design/date/_search/by_date?q=".$urlstuff."&include_docs=true&limit=200";
$ch = curl_init();   // initialize curl handle
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

And I get Bad Request.

If I replace:

```
$urlstuff = "[20180110 TO 20180119]";
```

for

```
$urlstuff = "20180117";
```

Then I get good results.

Is it the square brackets messing with my cURL?
What am I missing?

Comment: Can you see the detail of the response?  That might give you some more information.  I'd recommend trying the request without PHP to make sure that you're clear what you're aiming for - depending on the data types of those fields you might need to quote the values, for example.

Comment: @LornaMitchell in the console I get the same "Bad request" message and that's it! : /

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right track. If you escape your variable (e.g. using http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-escape.php?) your query should work:

```
curl -g -X GET   'https://user:password@user-bluemix.cloudant.com/db/_design/date/_search/by_date?q=[20180110 TO 20180119]&include_docs=true&limit=20'   


{"error":"bad_request","reason":"Bad request"}
```

vs

```
curl -X GET 'https://user:password@user-bluemix.cloudant.com/db/_design/date/_search/by_date?q=%5B20180110%20TO%2020180119%5D&include_docs=true&limit=20' 

{"total_rows":1, ...
```